# What is ふつ here?

Tags: translation, kanji

In the following sentence:

> ふつ~怒られるんじゃないかぁ~?

For context, the speaker has been beaten and is responding to the victory interview of the one who defeated him, which contains a lot of heartwarming stuff like how he's just happy he could keep a promise he made to his father. The speaker is accompanied by at least one other person (who also lost), but probably by more.

[EDIT: to better explain the context, because the above is faulty.

- C defeats A and B.
- C is interviewed by D.
- A (and B) watch the interview.
- A comments (to B?) on what C says in the interview.]

What is ふつ? The one guess I have at present that sort of makes sense is the affectionate meaning of 仏, so that it would be "How adorable~Ah, we can't possibly be mad at this, right~?" But as far as I understand that would require the ほとけ reading.

Sort of a backup guess is that it's short for ふつふつ, but if so I don't know how to apply that.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Reading through the comments, I'm sorry for the trouble I've caused. I'm very grateful for all the help I've been given and I hope you all have a nice day.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't think ~ is ー. The lettertype used has a very clear difference between any and all stripes (~, ー (katakana), and 一 (kanji)) and on top of that, ~ has in no other line been used as a substitute for an elongated sound (on it's own, anyway).  Maybe I'm not getting what you're saying?

Comment: So the speaker on question is C, and speaking to him/herself or another person?

Comment: @KentaroTomono In my edit, the speaker is A. C is being spoken about. And B responds to A with ボクもそう思うネ…

Answer (score 10):

The word you're seeing is ふつ～, which is 普通【ふつう】 ("normally", "usually") written in a slangy/sloppy way. This `～` is not a tilde but a [wave dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Wave_dash), which is used in place of a standard long vowel marker (ー). Notice the width of the character. In vertical writing it's rotated 90 degrees. You can write like おか～さん instead of おかあさん, そ～です instead of そうです, and so on (never do this in formal settings.) 仏 has nothing to do with this sentence.

> A: ふつ～怒られるんじゃないかぁ～
> A: Normally, I guess he (the interviewee, C) would be scolded (if he says such a thing)?

---

Here's the relevant explanation from Wikipedia:

> ### Japanese punctuation
>
> #### [Wave Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Wave_dash)
>
> The wave dash 〜 (波ダッシュ nami dasshu, wave dash) resembles a lengthened tilde (FULLWIDTH TILDE), which does not exist in JIS X 0208.
>
> Uses in Japanese include:
>
> - To indicate a long or drawn-out vowel (ですよね〜 or あ〜〜〜), usually for comic or cute effect

Comment: I'm starting to see where the gaps in my understanding are located (as others point out too, I might very well be getting the sentence's subjects mixed up). I'm going back to my translation and review some things. If I don't leave another comment, my problem has been solved. Thanks everyone for all the help!

Comment: @Andrew Naruto's answer is O.K. So I will upvote too. By the way, next time you ask the question, could you simplify the "context" thing as much as possible? Otherwise, at the start I had no idea who is the speaker and his/her relationship with father and others was a complete puzzle.lol.

Comment: @KentaroTomono I will! I did not handle this well at all and I'll make sure it'll be better a next time. Thank you all for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

This is easy as pie.

Here, ふつ～ is the Japanese **colloquial** version of Kanji 普通｛ふつう｝, meaning typically, normally, ordinarily, naturally etc etc.

So I was provided with more context by the OP at edited version, saying,

> C defeats A and B.
>
> C is interviewed by D.
>
> A (and B) watch the interview.
>
> A comments (to B?) on what C says in the interview.]

And at the comment line,

> @KentaroTomono In my edit, the speaker is A. C is being spoken about. And B responds to A with ボクもそう思うネ…

Then the conversation? utterance? would be like this, I think.

A, the defeated speaker, is speaking to B, ( not to himself probably ( because in the edit, it is described "corresponds to **B?**" )).

And I am sorry, I was a bit perplexed who is scolded, so that is the speaker A talking about C's attitude?
Then

> "Normally C is gonna be yelled at ( by his father ) ( or by his master? ) later if C says such a thing"?

( And B is responding to A with ボクもそう思うネ… )

And yes, ふつ～ is a bit of colloquial version of ふつう/普通｛ふつう｝.

仏｛ふつ｝ means France in old usage by the way.

And

> Sort of a backup guess is that it's short for ふつふつ, but if so I don't know how to apply that.

ふつふつ is the Japanese Hiragana of 沸々{ふつふつ｝, in which you can imagine hot water simmering, so there is nothing to do with this "conversation".

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88846/discussion-on-answer-by-kentaro-tomono-what-is--here).